# Why is this coroutine is not serializing properly non iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I thought it would be related to iOS/json and using if `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(string))`
but I switched that out and this coroutine is still not working. This works perfectly in the Unity Editor, but when build for iOS, this does not work. Could it be related to using null fields in the json itself? The null fields are important to the data structure of this project. For reference as to what the json does, each website is given an index from its placement in the hierarchy, and then the index number is matched with "Active Tab" object.

Example of json:

```
{
"tabList": [
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://www.usa.com/",
    "https://www.nyc.com/",
    ""
],
"activeTab": 2
}
```

and the coroutine in question:

```
public  IEnumerator LoadTabs()
{
    jsonPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/tabs.json";
    if(File.Exists(jsonPath)){
        string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
        tabsObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<Tabs>(json);
        //If tabs exit in JSON
        if (tabsObject != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Loading tabs from JSON File.");
            // Populate new webviews for saved tabs
            foreach(string tabURL in tabsObject.tabList){

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tabURL))
                {
                    Debug.Log("null or empty");
                    browserControl.NewWebViewLoad(tabURL);
                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("not null or empty");

                    browserControl.NewWebView(tabURL);
                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

                }
            }

            //Wait until all tabs are populated
            while (tabs[tabs.Count - 1].tabIndex == -1)
            {

                yield return null;

            }

            //Select active tab from tablist using JSON property.
            // COULD CHANGE ACTIVE TAB FROM tabURL TO INDEX IN TABS
            for (int i = 0; i < tabs.Count; i++){
                if(tabs[i].tabIndex == tabsObject.activeTab )
                {
                    SelectTab(tabs[i]);
                    break;
                }       
            }
        }
        else {
            // Create new tabs object if json exists but is empty.
            tabsObject = new Tabs();
            Debug.Log("No tabs saved opening a new webview.");
            browserControl.NewWebViewLoad("");
        }
    } else {
        //Create tab json if it doesnt exist.
        File.WriteAllText(jsonPath,"");
        tabsObject = new Tabs();
        browserControl.NewWebViewLoad("");
      
        Debug.Log("No tabs JSON File opening a new webview.");
    }

    allTabsLoaded = true;

    tabCounter.text = tabs.Count.ToString();

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the `Tabs` implementation? And are you sure you have put your file into the correct path on your iOS device? Have you checked your log file for any errors? What exactly does "not work" mean? What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

After going through my code I took out all debugging lines that used the json data and I stopped getting the error. Look at your debugging if you are getting an error related to parsing json data with Unity.